# Grid.ShowGridLines in windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

What is the best way to show the lines of a grid control in a windows store app?
I want something like Grid.ShowGridLines but I found that this is missing from WinRT.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that I can think of that would give the kind of effect you want would be to us the border element to put borders around every control in a grid cell, though it would probably be a bit fiddly

Comment: Or set background colours to see where they are on screen. I wonder if a custom attached property would work?